# Tabular inside a figure or a table

Tags: tables, floats

What is the difference between a figure and a table, when the content consists of tabulars?

Comment: The main difference between `figure` and `table` is the label assigned to the caption, either “Figure” or “Table”. What you put inside the environments is up to you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both environments can take take any content, graphics, tables or just plain text. the difference is that `\caption` numbers tables and figures separately and the latex float placement algorithm will keep tables in sequence with other tables and figures in sequence with other figures. However figures may float past tables, and tables my float past figures.

Comment: what do you mean "tables float past figures" ? I have put a `tabular` inside my figure and it goes outside the page. But when I put it inside `table` it is correctly sized. Any idea why?

Comment: @CiprianTomoiagă putting a tabular in a table has no effect on a table size.  By "floating past" I meant if you have `\begin{table}...\caption{aaa}\end{table}\begin{table}...\caption{bbb}\end{table}` then aaa will print before bbb, but if you have  `\begin{table}...\caption{aaa}\end{table}\begin{figure}...\caption{bbb}\end{figure}` then aaa may print before or after bbb depending which order fits better in the document